# unable to find spring bean xml file in another module of application

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

My application has two separate maven projects.The first project is core project which has dao and bean classes. The second project is web project which is having spring rest classes. This web project has web.xml and spring-servlet.xml files. The core project has spring.xml file which has jdbctemplate and other bean definition codes like  and datasource information.

I have written this code in spring-servlet.xml of web project to import the spring.xml file of core project.

```
  <beans:import resource="classpath:/mycarecore/src/main/resources/spring.xml"/>
```

Now, when I am building the war file, the war builds fine but when I deploy the war on server and starts the server, it gives file not found exception for spring.xml file. I have given the project reference in maven dependency and I can see the jar of core project inside the war generated war. I have done multiple changes in file path, but it didn't help. Because of this, I am also not able to use jdbctemplate in my dao layer.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url for the classpath seems like an absolute url. This will work only if the spring.xml is located at /mycarecore/src/main/resources/spring.xml path on your computer. Otherwise you should simply use: `classpath:mycarecore/src/main/resources/spring.xml`.

From Spring documentation: 
"You can always use fully qualified resource locations instead of relative paths: for example, "file:C:/config/services.xml" or "classpath:/config/services.xml". However, be aware that you are coupling your application’s configuration to specific absolute locations." (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)